# Circuit for producing logic high when input is oscillating

Tags: signal-processing, oscillation, duty-cycle

I want to make a circuit which produces a logic high signal upon receiving an oscillating input voltage. In the past I have gotten away using an RC delay signal. When my input signal wasn't oscillating it was GND and when it was oscillating the RC filter would give me a voltage above GND depending on the duty cycle of the signal.

The last point is where I ran into trouble with the RC delay.  If the duty cycle of the signal was 50% then the RC filter would give me high enough a voltage to trigger my logic gates. However, with a 10% duty cycle the RC filter's voltage will be too close to ground and the logic gates will remain untriggered.

How can I fix this in such a way that I will produce a true signal if I see my oscillating signal? It is typically 50-400 Hz, with a duty cycle of 10-90%

[image: old circuit]

Comment: Note that your old circuit will also think that something is oscillating if you simply apply a DC voltage to its input. It's not actually detecting oscillations.

Comment: If the oscillation stops, what voltage will be present on the input? 0 V? same as Vcc? A high impedance and no set voltage? How quickly do you need the output to respond when the oscillation is applied or removed?

Comment: If the oscillation stops we will see a GND signal.  The response would ideally be quick but should at least be faster than 10 seconds between receiving an oscillating input and outputting a true value.

Comment: @JonathanS. yes you are correct.  In my case though I either had an oscillating input or a GND signal.  This is why it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a retriggerable monostable multivibrator.  "Multivibrator"* means that it's a square pulse generator.  "Monostable" means that it just pops off once (as opposed to an *astable* multivibrator, which generates a train of pulses).  When you give a start pulse to a monostable multivibrator, you get back a pulse of a length defined by the circuit (usually a resistor and a cap).  "Retriggerable" means that if the thing is in the middle of giving a pulse and it gets *another* input pulse, that just stretches the output pulse by the design pulse time.

Set the on-time according to the frequency of your incoming pulse train, and the output should be constant on for a pulse train in.

* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator#History) says that the name "multivibrator" comes from the fact that it's got a square wave output, and thus generates multiple harmonics.  Hmm.

Answer (score 4):

A monostable multivibrator will work, but a rectifier and comparator might be simpler/cheaper:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY874z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Admittedly, we're talking about a difference of a few pennies here.